# How to convert two dates into month format c#

Tags: c#, date

Lets say we have two dates 2012-10-10 and 2012-12-31. I want to make a data entry into a table like this

```
Start Date                 End Date
2012-10-10               2012-10-31
2012-11-01               2012-11-30
2012-12-01               2012-12-31
```

Any code or algorithm will be appreciated.

Comment: You can't just ask for code.. What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: what you want to do? please describe more.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
class Program
{
    public static DateTime FirstDayOfMonthFromDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        return new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);
    }

    public static DateTime LastDayOfMonthFromDateTime(DateTime dateTime)
    {
        DateTime firstDayOfTheMonth = new DateTime(dateTime.Year, dateTime.Month, 1);
        return firstDayOfTheMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var date1 = new DateTime(2012, 10, 10);
        var date2 = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31);
        Console.Out.WriteLine(date1.ToShortDateString() + "\t" + LastDayOfMonthFromDateTime(date1).ToShortDateString());
        while (LastDayOfMonthFromDateTime(date1) < date2)
        {
            date1 = date1.AddMonths(1);
            Console.Out.WriteLine(FirstDayOfMonthFromDateTime(date1).ToShortDateString() + "\t" + LastDayOfMonthFromDateTime(date1).ToShortDateString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
2012/10/10      2012/10/31
2012/11/01      2012/11/30
2012/12/01      2012/12/31
```

(I pulled the first/last functions from [devprise](http://www.devprise.com/2006/10/03/getting-the-first-and-last-day-of-the-month-with-net-c/).)